# Can you load shared objects (libraries) and call their functions (FFI) from ABAP?

Tags: abap

Is there a possibility to load a dynamic shared object/library from a file on the application server and load it's functions (i.e. a Foreign Function Interface) from ABAP?

I am aware that you can call **kernel** functions with the CALL statement, but perhaps there are functions in the kernel that support loading libraries and calling their functions?

Comment: You did consider that the kernel may run on a Linux, Windows NT, AS/400, Solaris or several other operating systems? :-)

Comment: @vwegert All the implementations of FFI that I am aware of in various languages (e.g. Ruby, Python, Lua, Red, Haskell etc.) are cross-platform. This depends of course on loading the binary in a platform-specific way. (I used Ruby FFI for example to develop a wrapper around the NW RFC SDK library which works across platforms: https://github.com/mydoghasworms/nwrfc)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a kernel function that would let you do that. There *may* be one but kernel functions are certainly not publicly documented so you'd need to do your own exploration of the `disp+work` executable to see if one exists. And *if* you find one, you'd then need to determine what the parameters are. Not an easy task. If you're up for exploring, I'd probably do it on a Linux system and use `objdump` and `elfsh` as my starting toolset.

If I was trying to implement something like what you describe, I'd write a generic "library loader" RFC server in C using the [NetWeaver RFC SDK](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1025361). I'd use C, because it would give the most flexibility loading the external library. You'd need to handle the OS-specific portions of loading the library (eg, using `dlopen()` on a Unix system, `LoadLibrary()` / `LoadLibraryEx` on Windows), but you could then wrap the library functions in generic function module calls (ala, `RFC_READ_TABLE`) and call them dynamically.

Comment: I am busy poring over an nm dump of disp+work at the moment :-) There are just too many functions, and you are right, without documentation one cannot make sense of most of them, especially if you don't know their signatures. I also think that there is a whitelist of kernel functions somewhere you can invoke with CALL. That means you couldn't get access to LIBC functions directly :-/ Will try though anyway.

Comment: But thanks for the pointer (NPI) to dlopen(). Going to look at now.

Comment: Indeed, there is a whitelist of ABAP-callable kernel functions (contained in `sapactab.h` in the kernel source).

Comment: Going to carry on this conversation here if you want to join :-) http://scn.sap.com/thread/3771698

Comment: PS, I did not get your idea about the generic loader RFC service the first time round, but it sounds like quite a smart idea. +1